# How to model only the upper 25% of the response variable data using GAM

Tags: r

I'm wanting to set the below model to only consider the upper 25% of the response variable "Pres", rather than the entire dataset. I'm thinking the xmin and xmax line will need to be altered?

```
aa2<-gam(Pres~s(Mud,bs="ps", k=15),family=Gamma(link=log),data=Antho)
xmin <- ceiling(min(Antho$Mud[Antho$Bin==1]))
xmax <- floor(max(Antho$Mud[Antho$Bin==1]))
Mudnew <- seq(from=xmin, to=xmax, by=0.1)
pred.dat <- data.frame(Mudnew)
names(pred.dat) <- "Mud"
pred.aa2 <- data.frame(predict.gam(aa2, pred.dat, se.fit=TRUE, type="response"))
pred.aa2.comb <- data.frame(pred.dat, pred.aa2)
names(pred.aa2.comb)
plot(fit ~ Mud, data=pred.aa2.comb, type="l", lwd=2, col=1, ylab="Density per 0.0132 m2", xlab="Mud content (%)")
```

Thanks for any help here

--

Thanks, but I want to do the latter, that is model the "upper quartile explicitly".. is that plausible? I am using mgcv fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by only the upper 25%? Do you want the expectation of the data in the quartile of the response or do you wish to model the upper quartile explicitly?

One option for the former would be to take only the upper 25%

```
take <- with(Antho, Pres >= quantile(Pres, probs = 0.75)
Antho2 <- Antho[take, ]
```

then model using `Antho2` instead.

Another way, which you may prefer, is to model that quantile explicitly via the `rqss()` function in the **quantreg** package. I don't think it has the same wide range of spline options that **mgcv** does (assuming, you are using `mgcv::gam()`?), but it's capabilities are  good.

Another alternative would be to use the **gamlss** package and add-ons, though I have less knowledge or that suite of packages.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do the latter, that is model the "upper quartile explicitly".. is that plausible? I am using mgcv fyi.

Comment: You can use `rqss()` as the previous post points out, but not **mgcv**.

Comment: I understand I can use rqss() but as I'm learning how to write R code and my code is written for mgcv I'd prefer an approach that coincides with the above code

Comment: @user2673404 You **can't** use **mgcv** as it only models the expectation (i.e. Mean) of the response. At least I don't know how one would go about doing it - **mgcv** will try to fit the mean of any response as a function of the covariates. It is not designed for quantile regression.